# Changing %20 to - in URL using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i've an **index.php** page & have some posts on that.when read more button is clicked the user is redirected to **all.php** which contains full post.actually,the url on **all.php** lokks like this

> `http://localhost/project/all.php?rm=How%20to%20create%20jQuery%20Popup`

i want to change `%20` to `-`.
is there anyway to do this with **htaccess**.?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (remove query string)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+content\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# convert all space (%20) to hyphen
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [N,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

# rewrite rule to call actual PHP handler
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$ content.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: could you please explain where my page name comes ?